# how do I make iframe requests on html?

Tags: php, mysql, iframe, server-side-includes

I need your expert help with this question

since http requests can be made on webpages, apps, etc with...

- iframes (good example: facebook widgets)
- server side requests to remote servers (with: java, python, php)
- image embeds, video embeds (html)
- api requests (same as ss request)
- ajax requests (on same host)
- and more

1.) What is the main difference between these types of requests?
2.) Do they all use the same amount of (bandwidth etc..), for example if I use `file_get_contents("http://somesite/somefile.htm")`(php) versus 
the html version `<iframe src="http://somesite/somefile.htm">`, am I requesting the same thing or is there more 'weight' on one versus the other..

3.) What causes the differences, if that's the case?

Regards,
Avon

Comment: Why do you ask? The differences aren't likely to be at all significant for your application. Use the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question of calling a filename using file_get_contents and  iframe, the content returned is identical. However, the rest of your questions really depends on what the different implementations do. Usually you will find that

- server-side requests as are just the same as HTML for bandwidth, as the output is just pure HTML
- iframes are usually lighter weight, as they do not usually have the template (i.e. the stuff outside the frame) included in the HTML.
- image / video embeds is just a piece of HTML, but if the images or video are stored on your server, this data is usually a lot bigger than the HTML itself (videos especially)
- API requests are usually very small, as they return a very small amount of data to specifically respond to the request. However, if you are requested a LOT of data, then this does have the potential to be large.
- AJAX is similar to API in terms of bandwidth. Has the potential to be very low, as it only returns the data that is needed, but if there is a LOT of data, this can be quite large.

AJAX and API calls are usually the smallest however.